# What can be said about the terminal object in a category of pullbacks?

Tags: category-theory

Given a category $A$; consider the category of arrows $A^2$, whose morphisms are commutative squares, which are further pullback squares. Suppose this category has a terminal object $a \rightarrow b$. What can be said about it? For example is $a$ terminal in $A$?

Comment: Assume that $a\rightarrow b$ is terminal in $A^2$. Then, for any $x\rightarrow y$, we have $x=a\times_b y$. Hence, if $A$ has a terminal object $y$, any object $x$ is $a\times_b y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an arrow is called an *object classifier*. See [this nlab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28sub%29object+classifier+in+an+%28infinity,1%29-topos#definition) (in the link, see the part beginning "When $S$ is the class of all morphisms..."), which treats a more general notion, but mentions this case. The article mentions that object classifiers typically don't exist in interesting categories for size reasons.

<strike>I am pretty sure that if $A$ has finite limits and $a \to b$ is a subobject classifier in $A$, then $a$ must be terminal (a similar fact is alluded to in the last sentence of the "Definition" section of [subobject classifier](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject+classifier#definition) on the nlab). An object classifier is in particular a subobject classifier, so if $A$ has finite limits and an object classifier, you are correct that $a$ must be terminal.</strike>

But this leads to some hints about why object classifiers are rare. If $a \to b$ is an object classifier and $a$ is terminal in $A$, then $a \to b$ is monic. Since monics are stable under pullback, every arrow in $A$ is monic! I can't think of any example of a category with a (sub)object classifier and all arrows monic which is not equivalent to the terminal category.

EDIT
On reflection, I now believe that "if $A$ has finite limits and a subobject classifier, then the domain of the subobject classifier is terminal" requires you to take being a monomorphism as part of the definition of a subobject classifier. So some of my logic is circular. But it's still true that if the domain of your object classifier is terminal, then every arrow is mono.

Comment: It was musing on object classifiers that suggested the question; I hadn't noticed all the bundles would be monic, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Glad to help. It would be nice to understand more about this stuff.